# Invoke java program every morning using windows scheduler

Tags: java

I have a java code,which need to be invoke by windows every morning.But I dont have any idea how to invoke java code using windows scheduler.
Below is the snippet code i am using.

```
public class SchedulerMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {
        private String Filepath = "C:\\Users\\IBM_ADMIN\\Desktop\\OUTPUTZIP\\TESTCASES_01997.xls";

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); //

            int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);//get the hour number of the day, from 0 to 23
            int min = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);


            if (hour == 18 && min == 14) {
                System.out.println("doing the scheduled task");

                Desktop dt = Desktop.getDesktop();
                try {
                    dt.open(new File(this.Filepath));
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(SchedulerMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }

    };
    timer.schedule(tt, 0, 1000 * 60);// delay the task 60 second, and then run task every five seconds
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What can you do is
1) Create bat file `b.bat`

b.bat

```
javac SchedulerMain.java
java SchedulerMain
```

Save this bat file and use this bat file in your scheduler
Hope it will help :)

Comment: Runnable jar file (with pre-compiled class file) is a better option.